# problem in running teamviewer11

Tags: system-installation, directory, mkdir

i installed team viewer using following https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/427-how-do-i-install-teamviewer-on-my-ubuntu-system link. after installing, while running in sudo it shows--

```
Init...
 *** TeamViewer can not be executed with sudo! ***
 Either use your normal user account without sudo
 or use a the real root account to log in to your desktop (not recommended!).
```

and while running without sudo it shows--

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.local/share/teamviewer11’: Permission denied   
Error: Could not create '.local/share/teamviewer11/logfiles   
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.local/share/teamviewer11’: Permission denied  
Error: Could not create '.local/share/teamviewer11/logfiles  
Error: InitDirs failed. (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that directory

```
sudo mv ~/.local/share/teamviewer11 ~/.local/share/teamviewer11.bak
```

and try again Teamviewer **without** `sudo`

Comment: it helps @dadexix86